# I have odoo 8 database & I want to restore it in odoo 11. Is it possible?

Tags: odoo

If i have odoo8 database & I wanna restore it in odoo11.
So Is it possible ?
I really need this help & after i restore the odoo11 database from odoo8 database zip file it said "Database restore error: "There is no item named 'dump.sql' in the archive"". What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.

You should migrate your database to odoo 9, then 10, then 11 using https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade and then connect a normal odoo 11 instance to that migrated database.